# % yield in a Williamson reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

Calculate % yield in a Williamson reaction using the information provided below. Enter numeric value only (without % sign) rounded to the nearest whole percent.
[image]

I've done ether synthesis before but not sure what this is asking...

1.1g/2.1g=52% yield?

Answer (score 1):

I think they're asking for the *molar* yield (moles of product obtained divided by moles of limiting reagent used). The clue is in the fact that they give you the molecular weights. Should be 44%.
[BTW, what you've calculated is the mass yield, which is sometimes used in process chemistry].

Comment: I guess your instructor means that you can calculate the moles of product (1.1 g /172.23 (g/mol) = 0.0064 mol) and divide them by the moles of reagent (2.1 g /144.17 (g/mol) = 0.0146 mol), which in this case are equal to the 'theoretical' moles of product, so 0.0064 mol /0.0146 mol = 44%; or you can calculate the theoretical mass you would get if the reaction had 100% yield (172.23 g/mol *0.0146 mol = 2.51 g) and divide the actual mass you obtained by that (1.1 g /2.51 g = 44%). As you can see, it's mathematically equivalent.